# File does not contain a definition for "WriteAllTextAsync"?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm following Microsoft's quick-start guide on how to use [Azure Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) and inside there is a specific section where you go to create a sample text file to upload. However, I'm not sure what is wrong since this code segment produces an error which says `File does not contain a definiton for "WriteAllTextAsync"`:

```
// Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
string localPath = "./data/";
string fileName = "quickstart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

// Write text to the file
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

// Open the file and upload its data
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have imported all the correct NuGet and such but I can't seem to figure it out since this is directly their code.

Comment: It's .NET Core API, you possibly in .NET Framework. You may use `await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(localFilePath, "Hello, World!"))` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to check what version of framework/net core you use.
According to [this ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltextasync?view=netcore-3.1)

**File.WriteAllTextAsync Method**
Applies to:

**.NET**

5.0 Preview 7

**.NET Core**

3.1 3.0 2.2 2.1 2.0

**.NET Standard**

2.1

Comment: This isn't the issue in my case. I'm on standard 2.1 and it's still failing to resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to a microsoft explanation, hope you can find the problem : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltextasync?view=netcore-3.1

I think you need to include System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Comment: No, that wouldn't account for it's failure to resolve the symbol. Please also see [Stack Overflow's guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to provide adequate answers to questions here.